# How to change thickness of line in a Python plot legend, but not in the plot itself?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, which produces a graph with six different lines of different colors:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
import numpy
import pylab as pl

int_amp=[0.00,0.40,0.80,1.20,1.60,2.00,2.40,2.80,3.20,3.60,4.00,4.40,4.80]
masa_gr_circ1=[0.00,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.07,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.15,0.17,0.19,0.21,0.24]
masa_gr_circ2=[0.00,0.02,0.06,0.10,0.14,0.18,0.21,0.25,0.29,0.33,0.36,0.40,0.44]
masa_gr_circ3=[0.00,0.07,0.14,0.21,0.28,0.36,0.42,0.49,0.57,0.64,0.71,0.78,0.85]
masa_gr_circ4=[0.00,0.01,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.06,0.08,0.09,0.10,0.11]
masa_gr_circ5=[0.00,0.02,0.05,0.07,0.09,0.12,0.15,0.17,0.20,0.23,0.25,0.27,0.30]
masa_gr_circ6=[0.00,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.19,0.24,0.29,0.34,0.38,0.43,0.48,0.53,0.58]

fit1=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ1,1)
fit2=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ2,1)
fit3=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ3,1)
fit4=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ4,1)
fit5=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ5,1)
fit6=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ6,1)
fitpol1=numpy.poly1d(fit1)
fitpol2=numpy.poly1d(fit2)
fitpol3=numpy.poly1d(fit3)
fitpol4=numpy.poly1d(fit4)
fitpol5=numpy.poly1d(fit5)
fitpol6=numpy.poly1d(fit6)
xfit=numpy.linspace(0.0,4.90,num=1000)
yfit1=fitpol1(xfit)
yfit2=fitpol2(xfit)
yfit3=fitpol3(xfit)
yfit4=fitpol4(xfit)
yfit5=fitpol5(xfit)
yfit6=fitpol6(xfit)

pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ1, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ2, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ3, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ4, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ5, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ6, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(xfit, yfit1, 'b', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 1')
pl.plot(xfit, yfit2, 'crimson', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 2')
pl.plot(xfit, yfit3, 'magenta', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 3')
pl.plot(xfit, yfit4, 'g', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 4')
pl.plot(xfit, yfit5, 'teal', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 5')
pl.plot(xfit, yfit6, 'sienna', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 6')

pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

It is very difficult to distinguish some of the colors of the lines in the legend, so I would like to change their thickness, without affecting the thickness of the lines in the actual plot. Is it possible to do this? None of the solutions offered in similar questions I found on this site have worked, I can compile the examples but the thickness does not change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increase the linewidth of the legend lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706845/increase-the-linewidth-of-the-legend-lines-in-matplotlib)

Comment: For future reference, you should include the smallest code possible in your question that demonstrates your problem i.e. a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Most of the code you provide in effect just repeats itself, so it could have been made much shorter and easier to read

Comment: @DavidG It might be a duplicate, but those solutions don't work in this case, and that's why I asked my question...

Comment: @DavidG Sorry about the long example, I was trying to show why I needed to change the colors, but I should have made it shorter.

Comment: You also should include what you have tried in the question and why it hasn't work, then I wouldn't have flagged as a duplicate :)

Comment: @DavidG I'm using Python 2.7.12. I tried to copy/paste the code given in the previous solutions, and it didn't affect the width of the lines at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal example from your code works for me. It also works when running the full code you posted. I am using Python 2.7.13

```
import pylab as pl
import math
import numpy

int_amp=[0.00,0.40,0.80,1.20,1.60,2.00,2.40,2.80,3.20,3.60,4.00,4.40,4.80]
masa_gr_circ1=[0.00,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.07,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.15,0.17,0.19,0.21,0.24]
masa_gr_circ2=[0.00,0.02,0.06,0.10,0.14,0.18,0.21,0.25,0.29,0.33,0.36,0.40,0.44]

fit1=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ1,1)
fit2=numpy.polyfit(int_amp,masa_gr_circ2,1)
fitpol1=numpy.poly1d(fit1)
fitpol2=numpy.poly1d(fit2)

xfit=numpy.linspace(0.0,4.90,num=1000)
yfit1=fitpol1(xfit)
yfit2=fitpol2(xfit)

pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ1, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(xfit, yfit1, 'b', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 1')
pl.plot(int_amp, masa_gr_circ2, 'ro', markersize=5)
pl.plot(xfit, yfit2, 'crimson', linewidth=1, label='Circuito 2')

leg = pl.legend()

for i in leg.legendHandles:
    i.set_linewidth(5)

pl.show()
```

Giving the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. I probably don't know too much about Python and made some mistake while trying to copy the previous solutions. Thanks again, it works perfectly now!